# PHP header: is there any reason why refresh: url not working on a real server but location: works

Tags: php

I'm testing my CodeIgniter project on a real server. In codeigniter there is a redirect function like this:

```
function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'location', $http_response_code = 302)
    {
        switch($method)
        {
            case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
                break;
            default         : header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
                break;
        }
        exit;
    }
```

$uri is the real path. ie. https://www.realdomain.com/something.php

if I call redirect($uri, 'refresh'); then it's not redirecting. ie:

```
header("Refresh:0;url=https://www.realdomain.com/something.php");
```

is not working, however if I call:
redirect($uri); ie:

```
header("Location: https://www.realdomain.com/something.php", TRUE, 302);
```

then it's redirecting to something.php

I have traced it but there is no error, no warning. So my question is, is there any reason why:

```
header("Location: https://www.realdomain.com/something.php", TRUE, 302);
```

is working but not:

```
header("Refresh:0;url=https://www.realdomain.com/something.php");
```

BTW I'm running 5.4.24 apache centos

Comment: `Refresh` is not part of the http spec and is therefore non-standard. it's supposed by "most" browsers, but it shouldn't really be used at all.

Comment: @MarcB this is weird as it works on my localhost but not on a real server so that's why I think it is related to my server settings. BTW I'm using google chrome 34.0.1847.137 to test this.

Comment: I agree with @MarcB that it's best not to use `Refresh`, since the W3C is against it. That said, I am curious why your different servers are doing different things. Have you compared the Response Headers (accessible in the Chrome developer tools) from each server.